# Focus on first form element, whatever it may be. jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery modal dialog, when it opens I want it to focus on the first form element.

At the moment I have this:

```
the_dialog.dialog({ 
        modal: true, 
        width: 700,
        title: 'title',
        close: suicide ,
        open: function(event, ui) { 
                setTimeout(function() {
                    jQuery('#').focus(); <-- VERY SPECIFIC CSS SELECTOR PERHAPS?
                }, 220);     
            } 
    }
);
```

My problem is that the this dialog is called from a few different places in my application and the first form element can sometimes be an `input` or sometimes be a `select`.

The layout of the form is always the same, only the first form element is subject to change.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>LABEL</td>
            <td>FIRST FORM ELEMENT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LABEL</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LABEL</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LABEL</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Without adding any CLASSes or IDs, when the form opens, can I focus on the FIRST FORM ELEMENT, whatever it may be?

Comment: I presume `jQuery('#').focus();` is the line you want to adjust?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can use the psuedo `:input` selector within your open callback and look for the first non hidden element

```
open: function(event, ui) { 
       the_dialog.find(':input:not(:hidden):first').focus()     
 }
```

`:input` filters the tags `<input>`, `<textarea>` and `<select>`

`:hidden` filters any tags that are not visible from `display:none` as well as `type="hidden"`

Comment: The `:not(:hidden)` is a nice additional touch. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
jQuery('input,select').first().focus();
```

with respect to the comments, you should scope it so that it applies to dialog only, e.g.

http://jsfiddle.net/chkfgfwy/

Comment: what if there's an input in the main page?

Comment: this doesn't isolate the elements in dialog

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `:input` selector to find the first form element within the dialog:

```
the_dialog.find(':input:first').focus()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
// I'm assuming that <textarea> elements may be used, they can be removed if not;
// 'dialog' is an assumed reference to a jQuery object containing the relevant <table>:
dialog.find('input, select, textarea')
  // retrieving the first element matched by the selector:
  .eq(0)
  // focusing that found element:
  .focus();
```

```js
// this part is entirely irrelevant, and used only to vary the "first form element",
// in order to demonstrate the approach working, regardless of which element is 'first':
var formElements = ['<input />', '<select></select>', '<textarea></textarea>'];

$('td:nth-child(2)').html(function(i) {
  return $(formElements[Math.floor(Math.random() * formElements.length)]).val(i);
});

// the relevant part (explained above):
$('input, select, textarea').eq(0).focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>LABEL</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>LABEL</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>LABEL</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>LABEL</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).
  - [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).
- jQuery:

  - [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
  - [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).
  - [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: I haven't used jQuery modal (to my knowledge, or memory), I wasn't sure if `this` would refer to the modal. I have amended the selector in the explained code, though, to try and show the need/use of the context.

Answer (score 0):

would it be possible to us `<th>` tags to wrap your labels?

Then you could use

```
$('table').find('td').eq(0).children().eq(0).focus()
```

Although its a bit long winded, but would work if the child was a input, select or anything else (textarea etc)

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid I can't make that change.